# Disable notifications on a ContentProvider URI

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-sqlite

I'm looking for a way to suspend notifications on a given `ContentProvider`'s `Uri`. The use case is:

1. An `Activity` is bound to a `CursorAdapter` through a `CursorLoader`.
2. A `Service` may do a lot of batch, single-row updates on a `ContentProvider`.
3. The `CursorLoader` will reload its content on every row update, as the `ContentProvider` notifies listeners by [`ContentResolver#notifyChange`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver,%20boolean%29).

Since I cannot edit the `ContentProvider`, and I have no control over the batch queries execution, is there a way to suspend notifications on a `Uri` (in the executing `Service`) until all of the `ContentProvider`-managed queries have been executed? I need this in order to avoid the flickering caused by the continuous requerying of the `CursorLoader`.

Comment: To get this right: You have neither influence over the Service nor the CP? If on the other hand the Service is in your control, please provide a bit more detail about which kind of CP updates you're doing.

Comment: I am executing a series of "UPDATE or INSERT" kind of queries inside a simple `for` loop. I'm using a `ContentProvider` that notifies after every `insert` or `update` but, in this particular situation, I want to be able to suspend all notifications until I've finished updating all of the entities.

Comment: To be even more detailed, I am generating my `ContentProvider` with a generator by Nicolas Klein (https://github.com/foxykeep/ContentProviderCodeGenerator) that, at the end of an `update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)` does a simple `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot disable this mechanism in your Service. But you should try to batch them by using [ContentProviderOperations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html).

I've written an [introductory post about ContentProviderOperations](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/better-performance-with-contentprovideroperation/) and two additional posts covering the methods [`withYieldAllowed()`](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-contentprovideroperation-withyieldallowed-explained/) and [`withBackReference()`](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-contentprovideroperation-withbackreference-explained/) respectively.

Especially the latter one should be of interest for what you've described here.

**With ContentProviderOperations you can batch multiple updates and inserts. If you then call [`applyBatch()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#applyBatch%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E%29) on your ContentResolver object the ContentProvider executes them all at once.**

Now I've never used Nicolas Klein's generator but since he is a very, very proficient Android developer and works at Google, I bet that the generated code makes use of transactions *and* calls `notifyChange()` only once for the complete batch at the end.

Exactly what you need.

Comment: The piece of code we're talking about is [this one](https://github.com/foxykeep/ContentProviderCodeGenerator/blob/master/generator/res/provider.txt#L184), and I think Nicolas didn't put any notification in there because there's no table-level `Uri` to be notified, as any given `Operation` may work on any `Uri`.

Am I correct?

Comment: You can use a generic URI. That's what ContactsContract and CalendarContract are doing. They notify you at the end of applyBatch using [CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html#CONTENT_URI) or [ContactsContract.AUTHORITY_URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html#AUTHORITY_URI) respectively. I suggest to add something like this to the generated code.

Comment: I could easily notify changes outside of the `ContentProvider` if I'm able to apply a batch of operations that simulate an `INSERT OR UPDATE`. Do you think that extending `ContentProviderOperation` and building a custom `InsertOrUpdate` operation is doable? That would solve it without messing with the generated code.

Comment: **UPDATE**: unfortunately, it wouldn't solve anything, as the `apply` method [simply calls](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.java) `provider.insert`, `provider.update`, `provider.delete`, delegating the notification to the `ContentProvider` implementation of `insert`, `update` and `delete`.

Comment: The `apply()` method is only called if your `ContentProvider` doesn't override `applyBatch()`. But since Nicolas' generator overrides it `apply()` isn't called. Of course you could call `notifyChange()` on your `ContentRersolver` object with some meaningful URI directly from within your service.

Comment: It looks to me that [`ContentProviderOperation#apply` is called](https://github.com/foxykeep/ContentProviderCodeGenerator/blob/master/generator/res/provider.txt#L192) from within the generated code. Then, that method will trigger a regular operation from the generated `ContentProvider`, leading to a notification.

Comment: In fact what CalendarContract and ContactsContract are doing is a bit more complicated. They store whether a batch is executing. If so, the do not notify within each of those insert-/update-/delete-methods. [See for example CalendarContract's method.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2.2_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/SQLiteContentProvider.java#SQLiteContentProvider.insert%28android.net.Uri%2Candroid.content.ContentValues%29) But you are right, **apply is called for every ContentProvideroperation**. I was off the track. Sorry!

Comment: Don't worry, I'm simply trying to figure out what the best approach would be, in order to test it and maybe submit a pull request with the desired behavior. The `CalendarContract` and `ContactsContract` implementations by Google make sense and are compatible with what I'm trying to do. All I have left to do would be an implementation of a custom `InsertOrReplace` `ContentProviderOperation`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Can you substitute your own ContentResolver?

You may try extends ContentResolver with your own class then and you will may override method notifyChange and realize your logic there.

Comment: The thing is I have no information about the executed operation in `notifyChange`, as it may be a regular one that will need to be notified or a "batch" one that won't.

Answer (score 0):

In your Content provider class, inside `query()` method before returning the cursor, just comment the code which looks something like this

```
cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a way to have the same result without modifying the generated code/generator.